# How to replace single quotes in a json like column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a column in dataframe with values like the ones below:

```
{'id': 22188, 'value': 'trunk'}
{'id': 22170, 'value': 'motor'}
```

I want to replace the single quotes to double quotes to use as json field.  I am trying:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].replace({'\'': '"'}, regex=True)
```

But nothing changes.

How can I do this?

Expected result:

```
{"id": 22188, "value": "trunk"}
{"id": 22170, "value": "motor"}
```

Comment: Take a look at `df['column'].str[0]['value']` You'll notice that there aren't any quotes there at all....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to special escape the characters, just use the opposite family.
And no need to use Regex neither
And you have to use `str` accessor to do string replacements

`df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace("'",'"', regex=False)`

**Works fine with string fields**

```
>>> pd.Series(["{'id': 22188, 'value': 'trunk'}","{'id': 22170, 'value': 'motor'}"])
0    {'id': 22188, 'value': 'trunk'}
1    {'id': 22170, 'value': 'motor'}
dtype: object
>>> pd.Series(["{'id': 22188, 'value': 'trunk'}","{'id': 22170, 'value': 'motor'}"]).str.replace("'",'"')
0    {"id": 22188, "value": "trunk"}
1    {"id": 22170, "value": "motor"}
dtype: object
>>>
```

**Fails with dictionaries** => Convert it first with `astype(str)`

```
>>> pd.Series([{'id': 22188, 'value': 'trunk'},{'id': 22170, 'value': 'motor'}])
0    {'id': 22188, 'value': 'trunk'}
1    {'id': 22170, 'value': 'motor'}
dtype: object
>>> pd.Series([{'id': 22188, 'value': 'trunk'},{'id': 22170, 'value': 'motor'}]).str.replace("'",'"')
0   NaN
1   NaN
dtype: float64
>>> pd.Series([{'id': 22188, 'value': 'trunk'},{'id': 22170, 'value': 'motor'}]).astype(str).str.replace("'",'"')
0    {"id": 22188, "value": "trunk"}
1    {"id": 22170, "value": "motor"}
dtype: object
```

Comment: It returns NaN for all rows.

Comment: Wait, the content of the column is text, I assume

Comment: well, id is an integer and value is string.  The column dtype  is object

Comment: Your column seems to be a dictionary already. See the updated answer. Use `.astype(str)` first

Comment: using .astype(str) it works. Thanks.